# Swift version & update Swift version

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm using `swift` script in my terminal and it shows

> Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.

Is it the right way to show Swift's version？

And how to update Swift's version to 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

You can get Swift 2.0 by installing Xcode 7.
You can get Swift 3.0 by installing Xcode 8.
You can get Swift 4.0 by installing Xcode 9.

You can get more information here: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: No, you need at least a beta version of Xcode 7 to write and compile Swift 2.